# pretty print kind of multiple equations with Sympy and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

Is there a way to have a set set of equations like:

`Eq(expr1,expr2) and Eq(expr2,expr3)`

pretty printed in a Jupyter Notebook so it would look like this:

```
expr1=expr2=expr3
```

Answer (score 0):

The following does what you need:

```py
Eq(Eq(expr1,expr2),expr3, evaluate=False)
```

EDIT:
I suggest a more general solution like so:

```py
from IPython.display import display_latex
from sympy import latex

def display_eqs(left,*args):
    tex = "\[ " + left 
    for arg in args:
        tex+= "=" + arg
    tex+=" \]"
    display_latex(tex,raw=True)
```